# Запрос в бд для получения методов оплаты продукта по id продукта

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysqli, opencart

Какой запрос в бд использовать, что бы получить методы оплаты продукта по id продукта? Не могу найти связь в бд между продуктом и методом оплаты.

Answer (score 1):

Связь вы не найдёте, т.к. к товару методы оплаты не подвязываются. В опенкарте методы оплаты включаются в целом для всего сайта, а не для определенного товара